# getting message "we are unable to validate your information" during paypal transaction

Tags: paypal

I am using sandbox acc. to test my paypal recurring payment but i donot know why it is showing message :-

**"we are unable to validate your information. Please try again Return to facilitator account's Test Store
At this time, we are unable to process your request. Please return to facilitator account's Test Store and try another option.
".**

Answer (score 14):

Try to delete every paypal-related cookie and try again. Several users have complained about problems on the sandbox, and this method worked for me, too.

Comment: Be sure that you actually removed the Paypal cookies, not the ones from the domain where your application is located.

Comment: it works after deleting the cookies.. but can you please tell me how can I detect the paypal cookies and delete them before making payment so that user of my site will never face this issue.

Comment: The problem has been reporting only on the sandbox. Your users, using the live paypal version, shouldn't have this issue